# Controlling multiple thread flows in Python with start_new_thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm getting confusing results developing a workflow that repeats a quick process that need to run on an accurate schedule, with each instance succeeded by a slower function that can run in its own time.  The code is:

```
from thread import start_new_thread
import datetime
import time

# log text with current timestamp
def log_event(msg=''):
  with open('log.txt', "a") as myfile:
    timestring = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    myfile.write(timestring + ' - ' + msg + '\n')

def new_thread(asynchronous, stage): 
    stage -= 1
    if stage < 0:
        return

    if asynchronous:
        log_event( 'new process, stage ' + str(stage) )
        start_new_thread(new_thread, (False, stage))
        log_event( 'start slow process, stage ' + str(stage) )
        time.sleep(5) # simulate slow process to run asynchronously
        log_event( 'end slow process, stage ' + str(stage) )

    else:
        log_event( 'continuing process, stage ' + str(stage) )
        time.sleep(2)
        start_new_thread(new_thread, (True, stage))

new_thread(True, 3)
log_event('end')
```

.. which logs the following:

```
2014-03-12 21:11:18 - new process, stage 2
2014-03-12 21:11:18 - continuing process, stage 1
2014-03-12 21:11:18 - start slow process, stage 2
2014-03-12 21:11:20 - new process, stage 0
2014-03-12 21:11:20 - start slow process, stage 0
2014-03-12 21:11:23 - end slow process, stage 2
2014-03-12 21:11:23 - end
2014-03-12 21:11:25 - end slow process, stage 0
```

I'm confused why a couple of reports are missing - e.g. `new process, stage 1`, `continuing process` for stages 0 and 2, etc.  I'm also confused by the strange ordering: e.g. I'd expect the slow processes to start and end in order.  I'm probably missing something about how this works.

Very grateful for an idea of where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using low-level `thread` instead of high(er) level `threading`?

Comment: No I'm fairly new to threading so would appreciate advice on any improved workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of code is the kind of code wich makes people *not* recomend threads at all - you are probably getting a race condition on the oppening of the log file, since you re-open it in each thread. 
Even though you are "sleeping" large intervals, you are also starting some of the threads without interval between their start - (each pair of "asynchronous" and "synchronous" new threads have no artificial wait (call to `sleep`), just a couple of lines of code separating them). So what is likely going on is that the log file is been written, with different file descriptors, at the same time, and one of these writes is simply being discarded.

For this to work you could open the log file globally for the program, and re-use the open-file  object in all threads - that way, the O.S. will likely handle multiple calls to write on the file. But, on the other hand, as you can see, this kind of problem will only scale up as your system grows: that is why the "big news" in the new Python version is the asynchronous framework called [asyncio](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio.html) (A.K.A. Tulip) - which has been backported for older Pythona, including Python 2.7 as  [Trollius](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trollius) - they offer a different paradigm to concurrent programing than threads, and it is worth some attention if the project you are working on is important.

Comment: Thanks jsbueno for pointing me in a better direction. I'll read up on the awesomely named Trollius.